# What do you call the act of going out publicly as the president in order to celeberate with the people?

Tags: word-request

JFK was assassinated while he was out on a *.

I am wondering if there's a word for going out on a car for a public celebration, like JFK did before he was assassinated? I am not sure if there's a word for it.

Comment: As a general term there is a **walkabout** in the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/walkabout) and in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/walkabout), although it is not by car. *Many people gathered to meet the Queen during her walkabout.*

Comment: @WeatherVane   "Walkabout" is a very Australian term, though. and has a pretty specific meaning there.  It's possible the definition of the term has broadened and become more widespread, but it's not something I hear in this context.

Comment: @Andrew, yes it does seem to have broadened in BrE to cover famous people mingling with the public.I thought it would be a relevant angle though not an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best words for this situation would be those below, particularly if combined with "campaign."

> Visit (Campaign visit)
>
> Tour (Campaign tour)
>
> Stop (Campaign stop)